# Conditionally rank subset of partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to rank the below result set.

| AccountID | FacilityName | AccountNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Retail | ABC-1000 |
| 2000 | Retail | ABC-2000 |
| 3000 | Non-Retail 123 | ABC-3000 |
| 500 | Non-Retail 456 | ABC-500 |
| 10000 | Retail | XYZ-10000 |
| 200 | Non-Retail 123 | XYZ-200 |
| 300 | Non-Retail 456 | XYZ-300 |

I want to partition the rows by the substring to the left of the dash in AccountNumber (i.e. "ABC" and "XYZ" would each be considered a partition).

I then want to rank the rows of each partition in the below manner.

1. Any accounts that belong to Retail facility are ranked first (by AccountID ascending)
2. All other accounts are then subsequently ranked by their AccountID, starting at the max rank obtained in step 1

The desired ranking is below.

| AccountID | FacilityName | AccountNumber | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Retail | ABC-1000 | 1 |
| 2000 | Retail | ABC-2000 | 2 |
| 500 | Non-Retail 456 | ABC-500 | 3 |
| 3000 | Non-Retail 123 | ABC-3000 | 4 |
| 10000 | Retail | XYZ-10000 | 1 |
| 200 | Non-Retail 123 | XYZ-200 | 2 |
| 300 | Non-Retail 456 | XYZ-300 | 3 |

Below I'm currently ranking based on AccountID for all rows of each partition. Not quite sure how to rank the AccountIDs of Retail accounts first.

```
IF object_id('dbo.AccountsToRank','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.AccountsToRank
CREATE TABLE dbo.AccountsToRank (AccountID int, FacilityName varchar(max), AccountNumber varchar(max))

INSERT INTO dbo.AccountsToRank (AccountID,FacilityName,AccountNumber)
VALUES (1000, 'Retail', 'ABC-1000'),
        (2000, 'Retail', 'ABC-2000'),
        (3000, 'Non-Retail 123', 'ABC-3000'),
        (500, 'Non-Retail 456', 'ABC-500'),
        (10000, 'Retail', 'XYZ-10000'),
        (200, 'Non-Retail 123', 'XYZ-200'),
        (300, 'Non-Retail 456', 'XYZ-300')

SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY substring(accountnumber,0,charindex('-',accountnumber)) ORDER BY accountid) AS rnk, *
FROM dbo.AccountsToRank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY substring(accountnumber,0,charindex('-',accountnumber)) 
                   ORDER BY case when FacilityName = 'Retail' then 0 else 1 end, accountid) AS rnk, *
FROM dbo.AccountsToRank
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order your rows by using `case` expressions in the `order by` clause.

Your sample data is confusing at a glance however, your output is not shown in rank order!

```
select *, Rank() over(
        partition by left(AccountNumber,CharIndex('-',AccountNumber)-1) 
        order by case when FacilityName ='Retail' then 0 else 1 end, 
         accountid  
        ) as rnk
from AccountsToRank
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion: Adding a very high number to the *AccountId* column based on the value in *FacilaityName* and ranking accoring to the value in the new column:

Here is the complete query:

```
select *,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY substring(accountnumber,0,charindex('-',accountnumber)) ORDER BY ranker) AS rnk from
(select *,AccountID + case when left(FacilityName,3)='Non' then 1000000 else 0 end as ranker 
from dbo.AccountsToRank)a
```